Can't clear transforms from pose mode of my armature
My pose mode is messed up and I want to return to position of rest position, but can't clear transforms in pose mode. When I go to pose mode the spine bone in the neck is green, which I read means constraints, but none show up. Using Blender 4.2

What happens if you go into the Data tab for the armature and under the Pose section, click on the "Rest Position" button? Does the armature move back to its default pose? If it does, then you can go CTRL-A and "Apply Pose as Rest Pose", then hit "Pose Position" button to put everything back to normal.

hello could you please share your armature or at least show some screenshots?

https://app.box.com/s/s1w1tcjdnenk07zlssrjenfhgebsmo1q

Did as suggested pose position is way off. Rest position is still correct at default and can't clear transforms in pose mode.

Here is a smaller file with just the armature: https://app.box.com/s/as70xskjy0eoqtg31qrtfmcaaw6i0kq5

Even though I'm not sure what's happening, just click on the Set Inverse button, it brings back the bone to its original pose:


Great that worked! Another problem, I get error when I generate rig. I've spent days trying to align every bone, but can't fix it. Here is new version of the armature: https://app.box.com/s/as70xskjy0eoqtg31qrtfmcaaw6i0kq5

Note, I deleted and replaced some of the bones. Do they need to have the name of the old bone?
